# Is there a universal icon that means "remove"?

Tags: user-expectation

I understand that using a localized word for **"remove"** or **"delete"** item would be the most clear way to communicate the action, however, we are looking for a universal icon to communicate this without the need to translate it into different languages.

We are considering the following and I would like to hear the pros and cons of each. Thanks

### 1. Trash icon

[image: trash]

### 2. Cross icon

[image: cross]

Comment: A minus character, Θ, as a button also conveys Remove, rather than Delete or Exit.

Comment: We considered a minus icon but that sometimes means expand / collapse and may look like an underscore or something else.

Comment: Either one.  Add the word Delete as a column header.  If that really is for IP RANGES then a techie is going to get it either way.

Comment: I'm still searching for data on Option 2 which seems the most universal to me but not sure if something else tests better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer: It depends where you are removing items to. A trash-can may imply that items are recoverable just as an 'X' may imply hiding rather than removing.

My suggestion would be to re-examine the processes around the 'removal' to find something that works contextually and is consistent with the way icons are used in the rest of the system.

Comment: yeah the real answer truly is No but I do think IT nerds have been conditioned to realize that clicking an X will make something go away - the trash can raises more questions than it answers

Answer (score 3):

Both icons are:

- Ubiquitous enough that they're as close to "universal" as it gets with icons.
- Used broadly enough that users -- particularly technical users who understand concepts like IP addresses -- are quite resilient/tolerant when it comes to figuring out intent for the button.

That said, here are some suggestions for your particular wireframe:

1. I prefer the `x` to the `trash` icon:

   - First, because you are using the `+` symbol for adding an icon, so the `x` provides better control mapping because it's also a symbol.
   - Second, from a visual perspective the `x` is a simpler shape to scan relative to the other text in the table (no interior space, the other 'outlined' objects are text boxes, etc) so presenting a row of them is easier on the brain.  If you end up using the trash can, I'd suggest removing the interior lines to ease scanning, maybe something like [this](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/227551/trash_icon#size=128).
2. It would be good to make clearer **what** the user is deleting. The `x` appears at the end of the row, but there is no border or shading for the row itself, so it'd be good to visually relate the `x` to the row.  Add lines, or use shading to do this.
3. The `+` and `x` are related functions, but the icons are very different (the `+` is encircled, thinner, etc).  When you rev the design you may want to normalize the two icons to communicate the relationship better.

Hope that helps.